# Vertical Align Bootstrap 3.3.7 buttons

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I can't figure out how to vertically align text next to the buttons in the following snippet. Any ideas?

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div id="actionButtons">
        <button class="btn btn-default">
          Cancel
        </button>
        <button class="btn btn-default">
          Certify and Submit (1)
        </button>
        <div style="display:inline-block;text-align:center;width:460px">
              Certification <br/> By Clicking Submit I hereby certify the appropriate procedures and approvals were obtained and the information entered is accurate and true
        </div>        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This will be viewed on devices with at least 1000px screen width, so when you run the snippets, please choose "full screen" to see the example.

Here's a codepen with the same code as above: 
https://codepen.io/upgradingdave/pen/dgzdKL

The snippet below is closer to what I was aiming for, but I was hoping to accomplish this without changing the html markup above:

```html
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row" style="height:100px;border:1px solid black;">
    <div class="col-xs-1">
      <button class="btn btn-default" style="margin-top: 30px;">
        Cancel
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <button class="btn btn-default" style="margin-top: 30px;">
        Certify and Submit (1)
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <div style="text-align:center">
        Certification <br/> By Clicking Submit I hereby certify the appropriate procedures and approvals were obtained and the information entered is accurate and true
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve] in your question. The code in your question is different from and not complete when compared to your codepen

Comment: To add to j08691's on point comment, what do you expect/want things to look like? Oh and what version of bootstrap is that?

Comment: Sorry, codepen matches exactly with the stackoverflow question now. I want the buttons to vertically align with the text. Currently, they appear to align to the bottom of the #actionButtons div. Bootstrap version is 3.3.7 as mentioned in the title. I wish I was better at css ... thanks for your help!

Comment: can you provide a graphic example of the output you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
#actionButtons{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  -webkit-align-items:center;
  -moz-align-items:center;
}
```

Comment: Your suggestion lead me to find `display: inline-flex`. It's still not perfect, but good enough, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For your instance, you're not really using the bootstrap grid, you could take what's in my example and put it in a 12 column row if ya want to get the spacing, but the cause of your issue is just the `button` defaults needing a display of `inline-block` and then that `<br/>` you have in there is kicking down a new line after "Certification" as would be expected.

Cheers

```css
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<button class="btn btn-default">
  Cancel
</button>

<button class="btn btn-default">
  Certify and Submit (1)
</button>        

  Certification <br/> By Clicking Submit I hereby certify the appropriate procedures and approvals were obtained and the information entered is accurate and true
```